# PHP - exec() method not executing

Tags: php

I am experiencing problems running the following PHP code:

Get_Words_And_Display.php:

```
    <?php
  require('Database.php');

      $word_w = $_POST['word'];
        $word_def = $_POST['def'];
        $word_cat = substr($word_w, 0, 1);

        $SQLQueryIns = "INSERT INTO all_words (Category, Words, Definition) VALUES ('$word_cat', '$word_w', '$word_def')";
        $MySQL_db->exec($SQLQueryIns); //PDO Object is assigned to $MySQL_db

        $SQLQueryGet = "SELECT * FROM all_words";
        $SQLGet = $MySQL_db->query($SQLQueryGet);/*Each value is displayed in a table using foreach*/ ?>
```

Here is what I want the application to do: 
1) User enters values in ***Create_Word.php*** 
2) ***Create_Word.php*** POSTS the values to ***Get_Words_And_Display.php*** 
3) ***Get_Words_And_Display.php*** processes values and displays the values

However the POST values from ***Create_Word.php*** is not displayed (There are no errors).
My Database works completely fine, it's just the ***Get_Words_And_Display.php***.
What am I doing wrong here?

Here is the Create_Word.php file:

```
                      <form action="Get_Words_And_Display.php" method="POST">
                    <div style="border-top:dotted; border-width:2px; margin-top: 10px; padding-top: 20px;">
                       <p>
                            <label for="word">Word:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="word" />
                         </p>                      
                         <p>
                            <label for="definition">Definition:</label>
                            <textarea name="def"></textarea>
                         </p>
                         <input type="submit" />
                        </div>
                  </form>
```

My ***foreach*** code in located within the ***Get_Words_And_Display.php*** file:

```
                <?php foreach($SQLGet as $AllResults) : ?>
                   <tr>
                        <td class="dataCell"><?php echo $AllResults['Category']; ?></td>
                      <td class="dataCell"><?php echo $AllResults['Word']; ?></td>
                      <td class="definition"><?php echo $AllResults['Definition']; ?></td>
                     </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Can you show us Create_Word.php? Also, you're vulnerable to SQL injections.

Comment: [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: "Each value is displayed in a table using foreach"... Maybe your problem is here... Can you add this code ?

Comment: Hi, this is a basic exam project. We don't have to worry much about security

Comment: You should use prepared statements because even your own input can break your query. Apart from that you should add error handling to your database calls so that you know what goes wrong when it goes wrong.

Comment: @jeroen Yeah, I will be adding error handling since it is specified in my rubric.

Comment: Seemed to have found the culprit: A typographical error - SMH. I've also been reading up on https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Security_Cheat_Sheet thanks for all the recommendations